# A question about multiplicative order

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, multiplicative-order

Assume that the prime factorization of $M=q_1^{e_1}q_2^{e_2}...q_s^{e_s}$, and $p^n$ divides the order of $a \pmod M$, where $p$ is prime, and $gcd(p^n,M)=1$.

Now, my question is:

How to prove that $p^n$ must divide the order of $a \pmod {q_c}$ for some $q_c$ that divides $M$?

I have a simple proof of the above question, but I don't know if it is right or wrong :

proof, since $ord_M(a)=lcm(ord_{q_1^{e_1}}(a), ord_{q_2^{e_2}}(a),....., ord_{q_s^{e_s}}(a))$ and $p^n$ divides
$ord_M(a)$, then, $p^n$ must divide $ord_{q_c^{e_c}}(a)$ for some $q_c$ that divides $M$.

Now, since $ord_{q_c^{e_c}}(a)=q_c^k \times ord_{q_c}(a)$, where $k \leq e_c-1$, and since $gcd(p^n,M)=1$, then, $p^n$ must divide the order of $a \pmod {q_c}$.

if anyone has any idea, please share it.

Comment: Assuming you're referring to the additive order, then order of  $a\ (\text{mod } M)$ must divide $M$, so If $p^n$ divides the order of $a\ (\text{mod } M)$, then $p^n | M$ which is impossible. Do you have a typo somewhere or can you clarify your premises?

Comment: Do you know the Chinese remainder theorem? Do you know that the order of an element in a direct product of groups is the least common multiple of the orders of that element's components in the individual factor groups of the direct product?

Comment: @GregMartin could you please put it as an answer, with more details, thank you

Comment: @GregMartin would you please check the above proof ?

Comment: The lcm step is a good start! Is $\gcd(p^n,M)=1$ one of the hypotheses of the statement you're trying to prove?—if so that's not mentioned. On the other hand, without that hypothesis the statement is false (consider $a=6$ and $M=5^3$, where the order is $25$).

Comment: @GregMartin yes sir, $gcd(p^n, M)=1$ is one of the hypotheses, i edited my question, thanks.